# WebUSB navigator.usb cannot be used to see if a browser got support

Tags: javascript, chromium, webusb

Since there's many Chromium based browsers out there I have been able to test if the web USB API is available using the `navigator.usb` object. But I have come to understand that many of these browsers don't respond to any request even though they have the `navigator.usb` object defined. Can I use some other way of knowing if the browser will understand the API?

- Opera will open up the dialog but nothing happens when I select a
  device.
- Kiwi on Android will crash
- DuckDuckGo on Android will just ignore my calls

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the sounds like a bug in each of the listed browsers and I recommend filing issues through their various support mechanisms. Given the current behavior I unfortunately have to recommend checking the User Agent string to detect browsers that have known issues.

The current structure of the Chromium code makes it easy for Chromium-derived browsers to get this wrong. [Issue 991759](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991759) tracks a refactoring which should make it easier for browsers other than Chrome to share more of the WebUSB implementation or turn it off in a less confusing way.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will go down the old fashion "User Agent" alley :) I have filed a report to DuckDuckGo since that's the one I personally use but at least Opera should address this. Perhaps the Chromium engine should have opt-in on these API's so that the derived browsers will need to actively "add support"